# Python JSON load Object

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON dumped string to an object. Here is my code:

```
def routePolicyDecoder(o):
    print o
return o

params = '{"__Cbr2IspRoutePolicy__": {"defaultPolicy": {"__RoutePolicyMatchAction__": {"actions": ["set med 0", "set community ABCD", "pass"], "match": "default"}}, "policyName": "123456789", "ispName": "ABCD"}}'
json.loads(params, object_hook=routePolicyDecoder)
```

Then I got output like:

```
{u'match': u'default', u'actions': [u'set med 0', u'set community ABCD', u'pass']}
{u'__RoutePolicyMatchAction__': None}
{u'defaultPolicy': None, u'policyName': u'123456789', u'ispName': u'ABCD'}
{u'__Cbr2IspRoutePolicy__': None}
```

Any ideas about why None happens here?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should check the indentation of your `routePolicyDecoder` function. It's not valid Python to have `return` outside of a function.

Comment: Not using object_hook=routePolicyDecoder returns a proper loaded json.

Comment: sorry. I mistyped, it has correct indent.

Comment: I have tested your code, no `None` but correct output.